# UIButton as subview: How to add an IBAction

Tags: swift, subclass

I have a subclassed `UIView`, which is `@IBInspectable` and add a `UIButton` as a subview. In Interface Builder, I can of course only see the `UIView` but not the subview `UIButton`. How can I add an `IBAction` for the `UIButton`, or be able to define in Interface Builder, which method to call when tapped on this button?

Comment: Do you want to do it via the Interface Builder only? Because you can use the `addTarget` method programmatically to specify which method to call when the button is tapped.

Comment: @TheGamer007 Yes, i would like to add it via the Interface Builder, so that I could assign different methods to different instances

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887510/create-custom-action-in-a-class-for-use-in-interface-builder